# VideoView inside a Widget - getting android.view.InflateException: Binary XML

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-appwidget

> **UPDATE**: Got a reply from Google that
>   it isn't possible:
>   http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11752&can=1&q=videoview&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

This should have been the simplest thing, but I can't get it to run.
The following XML layout will cause Error inflating AppWidget AppWidgetProviderInfo exception:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/video_bk"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">   

    <VideoView
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/VideoView"></VideoView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong here?
I even thought about dynamically adding the VideoView to the LinearLayout at run-time, but failed, so if anyone have an idea about how to do that - it will be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a bug report, and got a reply that it's a defect and it can't be done:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11752&can=1&q=videoview&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 0):

See documentation
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout